# Sankey d3 v3 to v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I having a weird problem i moved my sankey from v3 to v4 of d3 and i am getting error TypeError: source is undefined. it takes me to sankey.js here

```
links.forEach(function(link) {
   var source = link.source,
       target = link.target;
  if (typeof source === "number") source = link.source = nodes[link.source];
  if (typeof target === "number") target = link.target = nodes[link.target];
  source.sourceLinks.push(link);
  target.targetLinks.push(link);
});
```

}

i am using a csv for my data source , i am not sure it was working in d3 v3

Comment: Your data must not have a source property, or must be missing one.

Comment: I was under assumption in sankey.js file we dont need to mention data column . I am mapping my data column to appropriate source and target in my html code section.